# how do i rename the columns from unnamed:0 to columns with increment number in python

Tags: python, pandas

Df before :

```
    unnamed:0   unnamed:1  unnamed:2
0   Megan       30000      Botany
1   Ann         24000      Psychology
2   John        24000      Police
3   Mary        45000      Genetics
4   Jay         60000      Data Science
```

To the df look like this:

```
     t0       t1       t2
0   Megan  30000   Botany
1   Ann    24000   Psychology
2   John   24000   Police
3   Mary   45000   Genetics
4   Jay    60000   Data Science
```

I have tried to rename the unnamed columns:

```
testfile.columns = testfile.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', 't')
testfile = testfile.rename(columns=lambda x: x+'x')
```

Comment: How about `df.columns.str.replace('unnamed:', 't')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it from 0 to the number of columns you have

```
testfile.columns = ['t{}'.format(i) for i in range(testfile.shape[1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to reset the column names and add prefix to them

```
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T.add_prefix('t')
```

```
      t0     t1            t2
0  Megan  30000        Botany
1    Ann  24000    Psychology
2   John  24000        Police
3   Mary  45000      Genetics
4    Jay  60000  Data Science
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a convoluted way to rename columns. I don't see a reason to use `T` 2 times to just rename columns. Anyway, to each his own.  Just saying :)

Comment: That's a terrible answer

Comment: Why so complicated? Two transposes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.rename(lambda x: x.replace('unnamed:', 't'), axis=1)
```

output:

```
     t0       t1       t2
0   Megan  30000   Botany
1   Ann    24000   Psychology
2   John   24000   Police
3   Mary   45000   Genetics
4   Jay    60000   Data Science
```

Comment: as i have 30 columns is it possible to have a program that will increment as it rename

Answer (score 1):

try `rename` with string `split`

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: 't'+x.split(':')[-1], axis=1)

Out[502]:
      t0     t1           t2
0  Megan  30000       Botany
1    Ann  24000   Psychology
2   John  24000       Police
3   Mary  45000     Genetics
4    Jay  60000  DataScience
```

---

If you don't care about the digit in `unnamed:X`, just want the increment on `t`, you may use numpy `arange` and `np.char.add` to construct them

```
np.char.add('t', np.arange(df.shape[1]).astype(str))
array(['t0', 't1', 't2'], dtype='<U12')
```

Assign it direct to columns

```
df.columns = np.char.add('t', np.arange(df.shape[1]).astype(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is already increasing. You just want `t` instead of `unnamed:` as prefix.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('unnamed:', 't')
```