# Rename all columns starting from a certain column with special character + increasing number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose my data frame `df` has the following column names:  `['date', 'value', '20211010', '20211017', '20211024', ...]`

I want to rename the column names of `'20211010', '20211017', '20211024', ...` (that is, all the columns starting from `20211010`) to `t1, t2, t3, ...` continue to increase.

The expected new column names will be `['date', 'value', 't1', 't2', 't3', ...]`.

How to achieve this in Pandas? Thanks.

**Reference:**

[how do i rename the columns from unnamed:0 to columns with increment number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315186/how-do-i-rename-the-columns-from-unnamed0-to-columns-with-increment-number-in-p)

Comment: Are the dates sorted? Always in the end?

Comment: what is there's non-date column after `20211010`? still convert to `tN`?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. Let's assume that from `'20211010'` to the last column is in the form of date, these columns need to be renamed. Only the first two columns need to keep the original column names. This is also what my data actually looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, a robust method could be to use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
idx, _ = pd.factorize(pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y%m%d',
                                       errors='coerce'),
                        sort=True)
df.columns = ('t'+pd.Series(idx+1, dtype='str')).mask(idx<0, df.columns)
```

Example output:

```
Index(['date', 'value', 't1', 't2', 't4', 'other', 't3'], dtype='object')
```

Input columns:

```
Index(['date', 'value', '20211010', '20211017', '20211024', 'other',
       '20211018'],
      dtype='object')
```

##### robustness

`to_datetime` ensures that valid dates are used, and `sort=True` in `factorize` enables to keep the dates sorted.

Example on this input:

```
['X', '20211010', '20229999', '20211018', '20211024', 'Y', '20211001']
```

The output would be:

```
['X', 't2', '20229999', 't3', 't4', 'Y', 't1']
```

The invalid date is ignored and the `tn` are in order.

Answer (score 1):

If always the first two columns will be skipped and just rename the rest a simple way would be

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[2:]):
    df.rename(columns={col:f't{i+1}'}, inplace = True)
```

But this will not consider the name of any column, so if somehow you have a column in the middle that doesn't need to be renamed it will do it anyway

If you need to do it bulletproof I would go with the answer from mozway